# If possible, how to connect iPhone to an external device and a router programmatically, both WiFi

Tags: objective-c, ios, wifi, connectivity

I would like to create an application that connects to the internet by using WiFi. That's easy, but i also want to connect the iOS device to a standalone WiFi device. (Device is classified)

So basically i want to connect programmatically to two devices at once using a single WiFi chip

Is this even possible (couldn't find anything that proves so on internet). And if possible, how do i do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS device can't be connected to two different wireless networks at the same time.

Even more: you can't programmatically switch between the two networks - user has
to do it trough the settings application.

So: if the device is on the same wireless network as your router (gateway to internet) then you'll have no problems connecting iOS to internet and to your classified device.

However: if classified device is on a seperate (possibly AdHoc) network then user will have to switch between connection to internet and connection to classified devices's wireless network.

If you're the designer of classified device it would be best if you can manage the connection trough wireless access point. This would be the only way to connect iOS device to your classified device and internet at the same time.